# LINQ with group by and selecting columns from other table: "not defined in this context" error

Tags: linq, select, join, count

I am trying this query but it says c is not defined in this context.

```
var carts = from Cart c in Context.Cart
    join ci in Context.CartItem on c.CartId equals ci.CartId
    where c.UserIdentity == identity
    orderby c.CartId descending
    group c by new { c.CartId } into g
    select new CartViewModel
    {
        Name = c.Name,
        Active = (c.Active == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
        IsCheckedOut = (c.IsCheckedOut == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
        IsExpired = (c.IsExpired == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
        Items = g.Count()
    };
```

And here is my class

```
public class CartViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public string IsExpired { get; set; }
    public string IsCheckedOut { get; set; }
    public int Items { get; set; }
}
```

What could possibly the problem. I have seen all the examples with select they only select grouped columns. I want to get count from joined table and select all other columns from the Cart. I am new to .Net.

Note: Cart has multiple CartItems. So i need count in CartViewModel.

Comment: Of course it's not - after `group by` only the `g` is defined. See `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`. Why do yo group by at the first place?

Comment: if it is `undefined` how can i then `select` and `map` to my `CartViewModel` class

Comment: Do you need other aggregates than `Count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After performing `GroupBy` you have access to `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` via `g` variable.

Since you are grouping by the `Cart` PK, you can use the `let` clause to bring the first `Cart` info like this:

```
// ...
group c by new { c.CartId } into g
let c = g.FirstOrDefault()
// ...
```

However, a simple [Group Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) is more appropriate for this type of query, like:

```
var carts = from Cart c in Context.Cart
    join ci in Context.CartItem on c.CartId equals ci.CartId into items
    where c.UserIdentity == identity
    orderby c.CartId descending
    select new CartViewModel
    {
        Name = c.Name,
        Active = (c.Active == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
        IsCheckedOut = (c.IsCheckedOut == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
        IsExpired = (c.IsExpired == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
        Items = items.Count()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do it after reading an article. Here is the proper way to do it.

```
var carts = from Cart c in Context.Cart
            where c.UserIdentity == identity
            orderby c.CartId descending
            select new CartViewModel
            {
                Name = c.Name,
                Active = (c.Active == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                IsCheckedOut = (c.IsCheckedOut == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                IsExpired = (c.IsExpired == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                Items = Context.CartItem.Where(x => x.CartId == c.CartId).Count()
            };
```

Instead of using join, we can simply do it by using navigation properties.  Moreover, this solution seems perfectly simple and clean.
Here is the [link](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/) to the article.

Comment: Doesn't is suffer from the N+1 problem? I mean, doesn't it execute another query for each record found in the first query?

Answer (score 0):

Use Select lambda expression on g since g has the grouped record and then select the required column in Select lambda expression and apply FirstOrDefault() on it to get the result:

```
        var carts = from Cart c in Context.Cart
                    join ci in Context.CartItem on c.CartId equals ci.CartId
                    where c.UserIdentity == identity
                    orderby c.CartId descending
                    group c by new { c.CartId } into g
                    select new CartViewModel
                    {
                        Name = g.Select(c => c.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Active = g.Select(c => (c.Active == true) ? "Yes" : "No").FirstOrDefault(),
                        IsCheckedOut = g.Select(c => (c.IsCheckedOut == true) ? "Yes" : "No").FirstOrDefault(),
                        IsExpired = g.Select(c => (c.IsExpired == true) ? "Yes" : "No").FirstOrDefault(),
                        Items = g.Count()
                    };
```

Comment: this produces problem and says select can only be applied after query compliation